# Random slow queries in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I just created a function in PostgreSQL and it takes 1 second only, but sometimes it starts taking 20 seconds and keep as it is and then again it comes back to 1 second. what is the reason of this random behavior?
this is the query plan

```
    "GroupAggregate  (cost=22478.74..22497.45 rows=174 width=293) (actual time=285.564..290.971 rows=183 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: r."LastNameInitials", r."ResidentId", r."ResidentName", r."LocationId", r."ProgramIds", r."OhId", r."WingOrApt", r."RoomNo", r."RoomBedNo", r."LocationTypeId", r."LocationName", r."MedCartId", r."CountUnControlledMeds", r."SystolicBPLowerVal", r."SystolicBPUpperVal", r."DiastolicBPLowerVal", r."DiastolicBPUpperVal", r."PulseLowerVal", r."PulseUpperVal", r."TempLowerVal", r."TempUpperVal", r."BloodSugerLowerVal", r."BloodSugerUpperVal", r."WeightLowerVal", r."WeightUpperVal", r."Gender", r."DOB", r."AdmitDate", r."ImagePath", r."Discharged", r."InsulineSlidingChart", n."NoOfNonVerifedTotal", n."NoOfPendingOrders", n."NoOfSetDiscontinued", r."Allergies""
"  CTE res"
"    ->  Function Scan on "GetUserResidents"  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.945..0.999 rows=324 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=22468.49..22468.93 rows=174 width=277) (actual time=285.515..285.741 rows=3157 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: r."LastNameInitials", r."ResidentId", r."ResidentName", r."LocationId", r."ProgramIds", r."OhId", r."WingOrApt", r."RoomNo", r."RoomBedNo", r."LocationTypeId", r."LocationName", r."MedCartId", r."CountUnControlledMeds", r."SystolicBPLowerVal", r."SystolicBPUpperVal", r."DiastolicBPLowerVal", r."DiastolicBPUpperVal", r."PulseLowerVal", r."PulseUpperVal", r."TempLowerVal", r."TempUpperVal", r."BloodSugerLowerVal", r."BloodSugerUpperVal", r."WeightLowerVal", r."WeightUpperVal", r."Gender", r."DOB", r."AdmitDate", r."ImagePath", r."Discharged", r."InsulineSlidingChart", n."NoOfNonVerifedTotal", n."NoOfPendingOrders", n."NoOfSetDiscontinued", r."Allergies""
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1614kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5011.83..22462.02 rows=174 width=277) (actual time=65.320..247.504 rows=3157 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=5011.27..20266.67 rows=174 width=285) (actual time=65.300..228.995 rows=3157 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (r."ResidentId" = n."ResidentId")"
"                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=4977.26..20231.99 rows=174 width=261) (actual time=65.150..227.719 rows=3157 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (r."ResidentId" = eo."Resident_Id")"
"                          Join Filter: (((eo."Type" = 1) AND (eo."MarId" = r."MedicationId") AND (NOT COALESCE(eo."IsBatch", false)) AND (NOT COALESCE(eo."IsBatchAll", false)) AND (eo."Time" IS NOT NULL) AND (r."ScheduleTimeSpan" IS NOT NULL) AND ((eo."Time")::time without time zone = r."ScheduleTimeSpan") AND ((eo."Date")::date = '2020-09-09'::date)) OR ((eo."MarId" = r."MedicationId") AND COALESCE(eo."IsBatch", false) AND (NOT COALESCE(eo."IsBatchAll", false)) AND (eo."Time" IS NULL) AND (eo."FromDate" <= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan")) AND ((eo."ToDate" IS NULL) OR ((eo."ToDate" IS NOT NULL) AND (eo."ToDate" >= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan"))))) OR ((eo."MarId" = r."MedicationId") AND COALESCE(eo."IsBatch", false) AND (eo."Time" IS NOT NULL) AND ((eo."Time")::time without time zone = r."ScheduleTimeSpan") AND ((eo."FromDate")::date <= '2020-09-09'::date) AND ((eo."ToDate" IS NULL) OR ((eo."ToDate" IS NOT NULL) AND ((eo."ToDate")::date >= '2020-09-09'::date)))) OR (COALESCE(eo."IsBatch", false) AND COALESCE(eo."IsBatchAll", false) AND (NOT COALESCE(eo."AdminPrevMedsOnArrival", false)) AND (eo."FromDate" <= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan")) AND ((eo."ToDate" IS NULL) OR ((eo."ToDate" IS NOT NULL) AND (eo."ToDate" >= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan"))))) OR (COALESCE(eo."IsBatch", false) AND COALESCE(eo."IsBatchAll", false) AND COALESCE(eo."AdminPrevMedsOnArrival", false) AND (eo."FromDate" <= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan")) AND ((eo."ToDate" IS NULL) OR ((eo."ToDate" IS NOT NULL) AND ((eo."ToDate" + ('-60 minutes'::cstring)::interval) >= ('2020-09-09'::date + r."ScheduleTimeSpan"))))))"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 193290"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..14717.70 rows=174 width=257) (actual time=1.022..92.778 rows=3130 loops=1)"
"                                ->  CTE Scan on res  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.947..1.143 rows=324 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using "indx5_MedicationsView_ALFId_StartDate_ScheduleStartDate_RemoveD" on medicationsview r  (cost=0.42..14.69 rows=1 width=257) (actual time=0.020..0.279 rows=10 loops=324)"
"                                      Index Cond: (("AlfId" = 206) AND ("ResidentId" = res."ResidentId"))"
"                                      Filter: (("StartDate" <= '2020-09-09'::date) AND ((NOT COALESCE("IsDiscontinued", false)) OR (COALESCE("IsDiscontinued", false) AND ("DCDate" > '2020-09-09'::date))) AND ("ScheduleTimeSpan" >= '06:00:00'::time without time zone) AND ("ScheduleTimeSpan" <= '23:59:00'::time without time zone) AND (("ScheduleStartDate" IS NULL) OR (("ScheduleStartDate")::date <= '2020-09-09'::date)) AND (("RemoveDateTime" IS NULL) OR (("RemoveDateTime")::date >= '2020-09-09'::date)) AND "CanAdministerMed"('2020-09-09'::date, "DaysOfMonth", "DaysOfWeek", "DaysOfYear", "Frequency", ("StartDate")::date, "ScheduleStartDate", "NumberOfDaysOn", "NumberOfDaysOff"))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 40"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=4569.56..4569.56 rows=32582 width=64) (actual time=63.918..63.918 rows=68093 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 65536 (originally 32768)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3585kB"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on eomar eo  (cost=0.00..4569.56 rows=32582 width=64) (actual time=0.054..41.522 rows=68093 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((("Type" = 1) AND (NOT COALESCE("IsBatch", false)) AND (NOT COALESCE("IsBatchAll", false)) AND ("Time" IS NOT NULL) AND (("Date")::date = '2020-09-09'::date)) OR (COALESCE("IsBatch", false) AND (NOT COALESCE("IsBatchAll", false)) AND ("Time" IS NULL) AND (("ToDate" IS NULL) OR ("ToDate" IS NOT NULL))) OR (COALESCE("IsBatch", false) AND ("Time" IS NOT NULL) AND (("FromDate")::date <= '2020-09-09'::date) AND (("ToDate" IS NULL) OR (("ToDate" IS NOT NULL) AND (("ToDate")::date >= '2020-09-09'::date)))) OR (COALESCE("IsBatch", false) AND COALESCE("IsBatchAll", false) AND (NOT COALESCE("AdminPrevMedsOnArrival", false)) AND (("ToDate" IS NULL) OR ("ToDate" IS NOT NULL))) OR (COALESCE("IsBatch", false) AND COALESCE("IsBatchAll", false) AND COALESCE("AdminPrevMedsOnArrival", false) AND (("ToDate" IS NULL) OR ("ToDate" IS NOT NULL))))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 27491"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=33.85..33.85 rows=13 width=28) (actual time=0.143..0.144 rows=13 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on nonverifiedmedscounts n  (cost=0.00..33.85 rows=13 width=28) (actual time=0.044..0.139 rows=13 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ("AlfId" = 206)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1335"
"              ->  Index Scan using "eMAR_Date_MedicationId_MedDateTime_idx" on "eMAR_Date" em  (cost=0.56..12.61 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=3157)"
"                    Index Cond: (("MedicationId" = r."MedicationId") AND ("MedDateTime" >= '2020-09-09 06:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("MedDateTime" <= '2020-09-09 23:59:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                    Filter: (("AdministerType" <> 4) AND ("AlfId" = 206) AND (("MedDateTime")::date = '2020-09-09'::date) AND (r."ScheduleTimeSpan" = ("MedDateTime")::time without time zone))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Planning Time: 2.111 ms"
"Execution Time: 291.970 ms"
```

Comment: Custom vs. generic plans. Or something else. How are we supposed to know with the information you give us?

Comment: Could you show us the function, the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE from this function, but also the EXPLAIN ANALYZE from the queries that are executed inside this function.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I just added the query plan

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry but I not know too much about custom vs generic plan

Comment: I think its not prepared statement and is simple function

Comment: The function scan in this execution plan took 0.05 milliseconds. Sorry, but this is not sufficient information.

Comment: yes but scan always takes the same time and not more time than that. only query takes too long to give results

Comment: We still can't help you, there is still no query, just a (nasty) query plan. The complexity of the JOIN filters is likely causing problems.

Comment: yes left join lateral was causing issue with directly joining with table, now I added table to temp table first and then joining it and it is very fast due to that

Comment: maximum taking 400ms to fetch records with lot of logic and joins etc out of 2million records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the left join lateral which sometimes becomes very costly and starts taking too long time to finish execution but this is improved by filling it with temp table and using the temp table in left join lateral